# VB.NET: Searching list view and removing non-matching items

Tags: vb.net

I have a list view full of records that were imported from a database. I have a tab for the sole purpose of being able to search information using a text box in a specific list view column.

I have a text box and a button for the specific word search. When the button is pressed it loads the database into the list view, and highlights matching items. I want to keep the matching items (the ones that are selected) and remove the other ones as it makes searching easier.

For example, there is a column for the reference number, so if the user has selected reference number as the filter using a radio button then it will look in the reference no. column for any matching results with the text value of the search text box.

The code for simply highlighting the items (I found online):

```
If rbtn_BugReportSearchFilter_ReferenceNo.Checked = True Then
        listview_BugTracking.Focus()
        For i = 0 To listview_BugTracking.Items.Count - 1
            If listview_BugTracking.Items(i).Text = tbx_BugReportSearchCriteria.Text Then
                listview_BugTracking.Items(i).Selected = True
            End If
        Next
```

My attempt at removing non-matching items using a for loop:

```
    If rbtn_BugReportSearchFilter_ReferenceNo.Checked = True Then
        listview_BugTracking.Focus()
        For i = 0 To listview_BugTracking.Items.Count - 1
            If listview_BugTracking.Items(i).Text = tbx_BugReportSearchCriteria.Text Then
                listview_BugTracking.Items(i).Selected = True
                For Each x In listview_BugTracking.Items
                    If Not listview_BugTracking.Items(i).Selected.ToString.Contains(x) Then
                        listview_BugTracking.Items.Remove(x)
                    End If
                Next
            End If
    End If
```

However; it doesn't do anything, it doesn't throw an exception and it doesn't remove the items. I'm also wondering if there is a better way than remove the non-selected ones, and just directly finding the matching items and removing non-matching ones directly.

What improvements could I do to achieve this?

Comment: Set `Option Strict On`, it will tell you were the first problem is. Then check how may loops you have in there (second code snipped, where you cut out the outer `Next`) and what these loops are actually operating on. You may find out that you don't need nested loops (or selecting something there).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main problem in you code is this `If Not listview_BugTracking.Items(i).Selected.ToString.Contains(x)` ***x*** refers to a `ListViewItem` not a `String`

Try this

```
        If rbtn_BugReportSearchFilter_ReferenceNo.Checked = True Then
            For i = listview_BugTracking.Items.Count - 1 To 0 Step -1
                If listview_BugTracking.Items(i).Text <> tbx_BugReportSearchCriteria.Text Then
                    listview_BugTracking.Items.RemoveAt(i)
                Else
                    listview_BugTracking.Items(i).Selected = True
                End If
            Next
            listview_BugTracking.Focus()
        End If
```